# Pronunciation of Permutation/Combination Notation and Ordered Pairs

Tags: soft-question, pronunciation

Quick question: How am I supposed to pronounce (or read in my head) the following?

$P(n,k)$ or $C(n,k)$

Also, how am I supposed to pronounce (or read in my head) this?

$K \times M = \{(x,y): x\in K$ and $y\in M\}$

Comment: $C(n,k)$ is often pronounced "$n$ choose $k$". The Cartesian product $K\times R$ can be pronounced "$K$ cross $R$". The entire identity is then: "$K$ cross $R$ equals the set of ordered pairs $x, y$ such that $x$ is in $K$ and $y$ is in $R$", or even "... the set of ordered pairs $x,y$ with $x$ in $K$ and $y$ in $R$".  // I assume you mean $R$ and not $M$ as written -- typo, yes?

Comment: I'd say that right side of K cross R is the set of all ordered pairs x,y such that x belonds to K and y belongs to R.

Comment: So in general, an ordered pair (x,y) is read, "the ordered pair x, y?" And do you actually read the comma as in "x comma y?"

Comment: Well it is crucial that it is the ordered pair, not just a pair. To your second question i'm not sure that i will be able to answer suitably, since I translate to English from my native language, and I'd read comma as "and". (x,y) = "ordered pair x and y"

Comment: Also, how am I to pronounce a predicate such as $P(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would pronounce the first two "permute $n$ $k$" and "choose $n$ $k$". But the equivalent $\binom{n}{k}$ I would pronounce "$n$ choose $k$", which I think is a better name for the concept, so pronouncing it that way makes sense too.

In the second question, not sure if you're asking how to pronounce just $K \times R$ or the whole equation.

I'd pronounce the left side "$K$ cross $R$" and I would pronounce the whole equation "$K$ cross $R$ equals the set of all $x$, $y$ such that $x$ is in $K$ and $y$ is in $R$", but there are a million different ways.

Answer (score 1):

$P(n,k)$ is pronounced the number of $k$ such permutations of $n$ and $C(n,k)$ is pronounced $n$ choose $k$.